# Generating random tests

Tags: c++, bash

I'm using ubuntu 10.10 and I want to test my C++ program with several random tests, so I want to generate them. I wrote generator:

```
// gen.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int n=rand()%100;
  int k=rand()%n+1; 

  printf("%d %d\n", n,k);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int a = rand()%100;
    printf("%d\n", a);
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

Then typed in terminal:

```
for((i=0; i<10; i++)); do ./gen > $i.in; done
```

But the result is that all *.in files contain the same numbers. When I type:

```
./gen > 0.in
./gen > 1.in
```

and so on, then everything is OK - all *.in files are different. But I don't want to create them manually every time I need them. I want to do this in loop. Why is that and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put a delay in your `bash` loop so that it's not using the same seed every time. Because you're using `time()` as the seed, all executions in the same second will give you the same sequence.

A `sleep` should do the trick, something like:

```
for((i=0; i<10; i++)); do ./gen > $i.in; sleep 2; done
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because when you're seeding the random number from `time()` (an integer number of seconds) - if you run the program multiple times in the same second you'll get the same results.

If you want different numbers you should use a seed that will be different between runs.

Note that if you just want to generate a list of random numbers & you're on linux the devices `/dev/urandom` (non-blocking) or `/dev/random` (blocking) will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Change your usage of the old C random number generators with the new higher quality C++11 versions:

```
// gen.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis;

    int n = dis(gen) %100;
    int k = dis(gen) % n + 1;

    printf("%d %d\n", n, k);
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    {
        int a = dis(gen) % 100;
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```